# Does the Reciprocal Public Licence require notifications only to be given to the first original licensor?

Tags: licensing, license-notice, license, copyleft, software

If person A creates a work under [RPL-1.5](https://opensource.org/licenses/RPL-1.5) and person B creates a work based on person A's work, person B has to notify person A with the changes. If person A then uses these changes and continues to develop more changes, will they be required to now notify person B as well or not?

Comment: "person B has to notify person A with the changes" While I'm not an expert on the RPL, I don't see this requirement anywhere in the license; 6.4(c) requires a notification to "the software community" but not to a specific individual. Could you please quote the exact section of license text you are basing this statement on?

Comment: @PhilipKendall OK, then it's a notification to the software community